# How to sketch a tree with Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, tree, expression-blend, sketchflow

I created a WPF steckflow project under Expression Blend 2013.
I would like to sketch a navigation tree to demonstrate how users can select items in a tree. The tree should represent categories at the first level (Cat 1, Cat 2, ...) and items should be under each category node. It should be pretty similar to the navigation tree of the Assets in Blend.

How can I sketch this tree?

Thank you

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341405(v=expression.40).aspx) is for 4.0, but should apply the same in 2013

Comment: Sorry, I probably gave a bad explanation about my needs. What I would like to sketch is a tree  control (with a hierarchy of categories and sub-categories). It could be similar to [this image](http://blog.hardcodet.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/simpletree.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so what you're referring to is called a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can find and use by going to your "Assets" tab and choosing "Controls" then selecting the `TreeView` and dragging it to your design surface. Then of course you'll have to add items and sub-items to it.

Hope this helps. Cheers